# TC160G IC pin numbers

Tags: identification, cmos

[image]

I'm finding the pin numbers for this Toshiba IC. Google search results shows this [Datasheet](https://pdf.dzsc.com/88888/2007926936450.pdf), but it doesn't have the pin numbers written. Thank you.

Bonus: What does this logo represents? They're all over the places in this PCB. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, TC160G is a family of gate arrays by Toshiba.

A gate array is a silicon chip pre-loaded with transistors, gates, etc., and no interconnects.  A customer provides specifications for what gates, pins, etc. shall be interconnected, and the foundry builds that (metallization layers on top of the gate layers).

In short, it's a totally custom chip.  You would have to ask the customer who ordered it.

The logo appears to be [NSD Corporation](https://www.nsdcorp.com/).

Comment: Does that means it was NSD Corporation who ordered the chip in the first place?

Comment: Most likely. `ABS24201A` is probably their internal part number.